# Pagination of items by Number of Items in JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the HTML table with the id "display" that I want to paginate using JQuery. The code for the HTML table is given below

```
<table id="display">
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the  tag , I have included the Jquery Libray and the DataTable API.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

This is the Jquery script I have written for showing items per page inside the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#display').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run this code , the table does not paginate nor does it show the select box to change number of items.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you included `datatables.css` file? Check for any console errors..

Comment: Nope. But it still works without it. I added the Thead and Tfoot , the code worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `thead` `tfoot` and `tbody` as well otherwise the initialization will fail. Note that `thead` and `tfoot` need the same number of columns as `tbody`.

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display').DataTable();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
            <td class="cols">
                <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are using legacy options in an up-to-date datatables implementation.

`iDisplayLength` is documented here: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options. Note that this is "legacy".

The code you are using is a later version, so I suggest a look at these:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength
https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging

It might be enough just to replace `iDisplayLength` with `pageLength`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
        <td class="cols">
            <img class="imagedisplay" src="the_deep_sea_a16eb25rs_right_1_1.jpg" /><br>Deep Sea Horse Charm Necklace
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```